# Raspberry PI Zero Qt GUI Animation too Slow rendering performance

Tags: raspbian

I have using the Qt by cross compilation method by [this site](https://mechatronicsblog.com/cross-compile-and-deploy-qt-5-12-for-raspberry-pi/) instruction by this configuration:

```
./configure -release -opengl es2 -device linux-rasp-pi-g++ -device-option CROSS_COMPILE=~/raspi/tools/arm-bcm2708/gcc-linaro-arm-linux-gnueabihf-raspbian-x64/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf- -sysroot ~/raspi/sysroot -opensource -confirm-license -skip qtwayland -skip qtlocation -skip qtscript -make libs -prefix /usr/local/qt5pi -extprefix ~/raspi/qt5pi -hostprefix ~/raspi/qt5 -no-use-gold-linker -v -no-gbm
```

So when I added this project to my raspberry the rendering of it take too long.

> mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QWidget>
#include <QMovie>



MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow),
    newButton(new QPushButton("Button 3"))
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    const int rowNumber = 1;
    const int colNumber = 0;
    //newButton->styleSheet() "background-color:green";

   //ui->gridLayout->addWidget(newButton, rowNumber, colNumber);


    auto movie = new QMovie(this);
    movie->setFileName(":/Pictures/70a552e8e955049c8587b2d7606cd6a6.gif");
    connect(movie, &QMovie::frameChanged, [=]{
         ui->pushButton_4->setIcon(movie->currentPixmap());
    });
    ui->pushButton_4->setIconSize(QSize(220,220));
    movie->start();

    QWidget *datawidget = new QWidget( this );
    //ui->setCentralWidget( datawidget );
    datawidget->setAccessibleName("datawidget");
    datawidget->setStyleSheet(" #datawidget { background-color:#000; } ");
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{

}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{

}
```

And

> mainwindow.ui

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="enabled">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>800</width>
    <height>480</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="sizePolicy">
   <sizepolicy hsizetype="Preferred" vsizetype="Preferred">
    <horstretch>10</horstretch>
    <verstretch>10</verstretch>
   </sizepolicy>
  </property>
  <property name="mouseTracking">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="tabletTracking">
   <bool>true</bool>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <property name="styleSheet">
   <string notr="true">background-image: url(:/Pictures/logo3.gif);
background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);</string>
  </property>
  <property name="iconSize">
   <size>
    <width>100</width>
    <height>100</height>
   </size>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralWidget">
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_2">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>600</x>
      <y>210</y>
      <width>121</width>
      <height>111</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">border-image: url(:/Pictures/nero_smart_start.png);</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_3">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>70</x>
      <y>200</y>
      <width>121</width>
      <height>111</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true">border-image: url(:/Pictures/images2.gif);</string>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton">
    <property name="enabled">
     <bool>true</bool>
    </property>
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>40</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>16</width>
      <height>16</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PushButton</string>
    </property>
    <property name="iconSize">
     <size>
      <width>0</width>
      <height>0</height>
     </size>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="pushButton_4">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>270</x>
      <y>210</y>
      <width>261</width>
      <height>211</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="styleSheet">
     <string notr="true"/>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string/>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menuBar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>800</width>
     <height>22</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
   <widget class="QMenu" name="menud">
    <property name="title">
     <string>d</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
   <addaction name="menud"/>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusBar"/>
  <action name="actionss">
   <property name="checkable">
    <bool>true</bool>
   </property>
   <property name="icon">
    <iconset>
     <normaloff>:/Pictures/ss.png</normaloff>:/Pictures/ss.png</iconset>
   </property>
   <property name="text">
    <string>ss</string>
   </property>
   <property name="toolTip">
    <string>&lt;html&gt;&lt;head/&gt;&lt;body&gt;&lt;p&gt;&lt;img src=&quot;:/Pictures/ss.png&quot;/&gt;&lt;/p&gt;&lt;/body&gt;&lt;/html&gt;</string>
   </property>
   <property name="shortcut">
    <string>Ctrl+C</string>
   </property>
  </action>
 </widget>
 <layoutdefault spacing="6" margin="11"/>
 <tabstops>
  <tabstop>pushButton</tabstop>
  <tabstop>pushButton_2</tabstop>
  <tabstop>pushButton_3</tabstop>
 </tabstops>
 <resources/>
 <connections>
  <connection>
   <sender>pushButton_2</sender>
   <signal>clicked()</signal>
   <receiver>MainWindow</receiver>
   <slot>close()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>670</x>
     <y>310</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>513</x>
     <y>273</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
  <connection>
   <sender>pushButton_3</sender>
   <signal>clicked()</signal>
   <receiver>MainWindow</receiver>
   <slot>close()</slot>
   <hints>
    <hint type="sourcelabel">
     <x>132</x>
     <y>284</y>
    </hint>
    <hint type="destinationlabel">
     <x>162</x>
     <y>182</y>
    </hint>
   </hints>
  </connection>
 </connections>
</ui>
```

The animation gif is :

[image: main gif]

ANd the rendering in raspberry is :

[image: raspberry output]

So i use `eglfs` and `opengl`  plugins at somewhere I have seen maybe it could be related to this setting.

**

> Update:

**

> I have added `movie->setSpeed(2000000);` to my `mainwindow.cpp` file
>   but in raspberry speeds don't changed too much but in desktop kit the
>   speed raised too mush.

What can I do to show videos in my raspberry qt applications as the references rates?

Thanks